# Regular expression in Perl not giving expected answer

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to implement a regular expression in Perl. My code is

```
my $version=6.1; 
$version =~ /\d./;
print $version;
```

Expected output:

```
6.
```

or

```
6
```

Current output:

```
6.1
```

I tried the above method in regxpal and regxr where it is giving me `6.`. However, I get `6.1`.

I also tried:

```
$version =~ /\d\./;
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Should be noted - what you're doing there doesn't change anything, it's a boolean test. Which you're not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may trim all the chars except `\d\.`

```
my $version = 6.1; 
$version =~ s/.*(\d\.).*/$1/;
print $version;
```

Now, it would print `6.`. What you do in the code is, you just do matching only.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/njJ73i)

To get only the digit which exists before dot.

```
$version =~ s/.*(\d)\..*/\1/;
```

Comment: Ok thanks , it should be version =~ s/.*(\d.).*/$1/ instead of \1 I think.

Comment: This solution is very inefficient in comparison with the original task: just match the first digit and a dot and print them. Mind that your original code is totally fine, you just needed a correct back reference.

Comment: Where op mentioned that he want to match the first digit?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: The (corrected) OP's pattern `/\d\./` matches the *first* digit that is followed by a dot. Yours does not

Comment: make it non-greedy `s/.*?(\d\.).*/$1/;`

Answer (score 3):

You can also directly assign the content of $1 back to $version, like this:

```
my $version = 6.1;
( $version ) = $version =~ /(\d\.)/;
print $version;
```

This can be extended if you want to capture several groups as well:

```
my ($main_version, $minor_version ) = $version =~ /(\d)\.(\d)/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just capture the part you're interested in using parentheses, then it will be assigned to `$1`:

```
my $version = 6.1;
$version =~ /(\d\.)/;
print $1;
```

Output:

```
6.
```

To overwrite the original variable, you could go with something like this:

```
my $version = 6.1;
if ($version =~ /(\d\.)/) {
    $version = $1;
}
```

This will only overwrite the variable if the pattern is matched.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do to make your regex work is using `$&` backreference, and to match a  literal dot, you need to escape it or put in a character class:

```
print "$&";
```

See [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/qU747r):

```
my $version=6.1; 
$version =~ /\d\./;
print "$&";  # => 6.
```

See [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html):

> Even if there are no groupings in a regexp, it is still possible to find out what exactly matched in a string. If you use them, Perl will set `` $` `` to the part of the string before the match, will set `$&` to the part of the string that matched, and will set `$'` to the part of the string after the match.

Comment: Note that you do not need any replacements, or setting capturing groups that will decrease performance (though with such a simple regex, performance is not key).

Answer (score 0):

What I imagine you want is to remove any fractional part of a numeric string

This will do that

```
my $version = 6.1; 
$version =~ s/\..*//;
print $version, "\n";
```

#### output

```
6
```